# Reading metadata results from pyoai

Tags: python, metadata, oai, oai-pmh

I'm working with pyoai library on python3.7 to harvest metadata using oai-pmh protocol but i'm getting troubles at the moment of read list of records

```
from oaipmh.client import Client
from oaipmh.metadata import MetadataRegistry, oai_dc_reader

URL = 'http://revista-iberoamericana.pitt.edu/ojs/index.php/Iberoamericana/oai'
registry = MetadataRegistry()
registry.registerReader('oai_dc', oai_dc_reader)
client = Client(URL, registry)

for record in client.listRecords(metadataPrefix='oai_dc'):
print(record)
```

i was especting a kind of xml file on tuples, but the results are like this:

```
(<oaipmh.common.Header object at 0x00000251FAA16A20>, <oaipmh.common.Metadata object at 0x00000251FAA160B8>, None) 
(<oaipmh.common.Header object at 0x00000251FA9DB5C0>, <oaipmh.common.Metadata object at 0x00000251FA9C6518>, None) 
(<oaipmh.common.Header object at 0x00000251FA9DB0F0>, <oaipmh.common.Metadata object at 0x00000251FA9DB208>, None)
```

could you tellme if i'm forgetting something

Answer (score 0):

You can use `record[1].getMap()`

https://tinker.edu.au/resources/recipes/api-via-oai-pmh/